# ASP.NET error with Nhibernate

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I have LineBrand table which has many LineBrandLocalization. 
When I map it like

```
 HasMany(x => x.LineBrandLocalizations)
.KeyColumn("line_brand_id")
.Access.CamelCaseField(Prefix.Underscore)
.Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()
.Fetch.Subselect()
.Inverse();
```

and   LineBrandLocalizations is

```
public virtual IEnumerable<LineBrandLocalization> LineBrandLocalizations
{
    get { return _lineBrandlocalizations; }
}


private IList<LineBrandLocalization> _lineBrandlocalizations = new List<LineBrandLocalization>();
```

I get the error

> NHibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: Could not find field '_lineBrandLocalizations' in class 'LineBrand'.

What is wrong with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The naming is essential. Your field is

```
_lineBrandlocalizations // see the lower l localizations
```

while it should be

```
_lineBrandLocalizations // see the upper L Localizations
```

Comment: Great to see that! Enjoy NHibernate, sir ;)

Comment: I do, but I'm not a sir! :)